# Swift: ObservableObject, initializer doesn't define all properties?

Tags: swift, combine

Currently I have the code below which I'm trying to use as a navigation switch so I can navigate through different views without using the crappy NavigationLinks and otherwise. I'm by default a WebDev, so I've been having a mountain of issues transferring my knowledge over to Swift, the syntax feels completely dissimilar to any code I've written before. Anyways, here's the code;

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    let objectWillChange: PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>

    @Published var currentPage: String = "page1" {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init(currentPage: String) {
        self.currentPage = currentPage
    }

}
```

As you can see, it's really simple, and I just use the object to switch values and display different views on another file, the only errors which prevent me from building it is the fact that the initializer is saying "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties", even though the only variable is the currentPage variable which is defined. I know it's saying that objectWillChange is not defined by the message, but objectWillChange doesn't have any value to be assigned. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `objectWillChange` needs to be initialized before initializer returns. What is unclear?

Comment: Probably where you say `objectWillChange: PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>` you mean `objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>()`.

Answer (score 2):

You just declare `objectWillChange`, but don't initialise it.

Simply change the declaration from

```
let objectWillChange: PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>
```

to

```
let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter,Never>()
```

However, using a `PassthroughSubject` shouldn't be necessary. `currentPage` is already `@Published`, so you can simply subscribe to its publisher. What you are trying to achieve using a `PassthroughSubject` and `didSet` is already defined by the swiftUI property wrappers, `ObservableObject` and `Published`.

```
class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentPage: String

    init(currentPage: String) {
        self.currentPage = currentPage
    }

}
```

Then you can simply do

```
let router = ViewRouter(currentPage: "a")
router.$currentPage.sink { page in print(page) }

router.currentPage = "b" // the above subscription prints `"b"`
```

Comment: Might want to make clear that `observableObject` is already defined so there is no need to define it manually.